# Prove that, over a Euclidean domain $R, I + cE_{ij}$ generate $SL_n(R)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

> Let $R$ be a euclidean domain. Let $E_n(R)$ be the subgroup of $GL_n(R)$ generated by all matrices of the form $I + λ$ where $λ$ is a matrix with precisely one non zero entry and this entry does not occur on the diagonal and $I$ is the $n × n$ identity matrix. Show that $SL_n(R) = E_n(R)$.

Proving $SL_n(R) \geq E_n(R)$ is easy. For the other direction, I am thinking I wold have to use Smith normal forms or Jordan canonical forms. For Smith Normal forms, since $R$ is a Euclidean fomain, it is PID. we have that (without loss of generality) that any matrix $M \in SL_n(R)$ is $M = \mathrm{diag} (d_1,...,d_r,0,...,0)$ for some $r$. Because the determinant is $1$, we conclude that $r=0$ and $d_i = 1$ for all $i$. Hence the conclusion.

This seems way too simplistic. Am I missing something?

Comment: You missed something when you said "without loss of generality". So far, you've only proven that any matrix $M \in SL_n(R)$ is *conjugate* with some matrix in $E_n(R)$.

Comment: Also, when you say that since determinant is $1$, you probably wanted to write that $r = n$ instead of $r = 0$.However, I don't see how $d_i = 1$ follows from the fact that $\prod d_i = 1$.

Comment: Forget about Jordan normal form ($R$ is not an algebraically closed field). Forget about conjugates. You want to show that any matrix in $\operatorname{GL}_n\left(R\right)$ can be brought to diagonal form via elementary row and column transformations. This is what *some* people call the Smith normal form algorithm, but this is not universal (for many others, the Smith normal form involves left- and right-multiplication by arbitrary invertible matrices, which will be useless to you). ...

Comment: ... The sort of Smith normal form that should help you is the one discussed in §108 ("Smith Normal Form over a Euclidean Ring", if the numbering changes) of [Richard Elman, *Lectures on Abstract Algebra*, version 3 October 2017](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~rse/algebra_book.pdf). But it's not the whole story: Out of his three types of elementary matrices, only Type I is allowed in your argument. You need to figure out how to deal with Type II and Type III. From what I remember, Type II matrices can be written as products of Type I matrices ("xor-swap"), while ...

Comment: ... the Type III matrices need some more trickery. I think this is done in various texts on algebraic K-theory, such as Milnor's or Weibel's?