# How to write Type III matrix as a product of Type I matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I saw this question [Prove that, over a Euclidean domain $R, I + cE_{ij}$ generate $SL_n(R)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2691869/prove-that-over-a-euclidean-domain-r-i-ce-ij-generate-sl-nr) and in the comment section, someone mentioned that you can do something about type III matrices.

I tried to do this myself, and I noticed that you can use Type I, II, III matrices where I is multiply one row and add to another, II is swapping 2 rows, and III is multiplying a row by a *unit* to reduce a matrix $A\in SL_n(R)$ to $I_n$. I know that we can write type II matrices as a product of type I matrices, and if we use one type III matrix to multiply one row by $u$, then we must use another type III matrix that multiplies another row by $u^{-1}$. I wonder with these restrictions how can we write the type III matrices as a product of type I matrices.

Thank you!

Comment: You cannot, because the product of type I matrices (i.e. shear matrices) always has determinant $1$. You seem to have misread the comments under the linked question. What they say is that one may use only type I matrices to convert a nonsingular matrix $A$ into a *diagonal* matrix $D$, which is not necessarily of type III even if $\det A=1$. (However, $D$ can be *chosen* to be a type III matrix if $\det A=1$).